# fastAPI send data to list of user

Tags: python, django, api, fastapi

I am trying to create an endpoint where admin has created orders and team leader(tl) has list of employees, whichever employees the tl selects a set of 60 orders has to be send to that employees

schema for order cluster

```
class Orders(BaseModel):
name: str
car_number: str
contact_number: str
address: str
cod_amount: str
pin_code: str
emp_id: str
tl_id: str

user_collection = db[config["USERS"]]
order_collection = db[config["ORDERS"]]
order_options_by_admin_collections=db[config["INITIAL_ORDER_OPTIONS_BY_ADMIN"]]
```

ps : this is my first time creating an api, by far i have written this

```
@app.get('/send-order-to-emps-from-tls')
def Send_orders_to_emps(id:List[str]=Query(None, alias="Id"),userid=Depends(auth_handler.auth_wrapper)):
        emp_id=userid
        emp_data=user_collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(emp_id)})
        if(emp_data["tl_id"]==""):
            all_order=[]
            order_created_by_admin=order_options_by_admin_collections.find()
            for order in order_created_by_admin:
                order.parse_json(order)
                all_order.append(order)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I send orders data in a set of 60 to the list of ids

Comment: What do you mean by "send orders data"? Send how? Or are you wondering how you limit the resulting set to 60 entries?

Comment: their is a cluster named "orders" in mongodb database. which contains fields =
    name: str
    car_number: str
    contact_number: str
    address: str
    cod_amount: str
    pin_code: str
    emp_id: str
    tl_id: str .. we have to return this data to employees with max limit to 60 data

Comment: I want to know how can I send the data to the ids that are in "id" list as well to limit it.